# C:\System Volume Information is taking up 60 GB

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-xp, disk-space

I decided to do some spring cleaning on my laptop, and used a disk analyzer to free up some space on my C drive. I've managed to go from about 13 to about 33 GB of space, but I noticed that I was only using about 50 GB, and about 60 GB of my 140 GB hard drive was completely unaccounted for. Based on what I've learned from some research, a likely candidate might be my Windows XP's System Restore Points, but I've checked my System Restore settings and it's only supposed to use 12% of disk space, which should be around 17 GB.

I've got 30 GB of free space and a 500 GB external hard drive, so I'm not especially worried, but I'm curious as to what's taking up so much space on my computer. If it's important system processes, I don't mind leaving them be. But if there's anything I can do about it, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 5):

System Volume Information is the folder that Windows use to the System Protection (restore points).

To reduce it (or clear its content):
Right click on My Computer and click on Properties, then Click on Advanced System Settings.  In System Properties click System Protection, then click on Configure.  There you can adjust the disk space used for system protection and/or delete all restore points.
(This is in Win7)

Comment: Thanks for the response! But as I said, I think that's only accounting for about 17 GB. I've been looking into it more and while I'm not sure, I may have narrowed it down to Lenovo's Rescue and Recovery backups (apparently it made 5 since I first got my laptop, with the first being 44 GB!). I'm still checking it out though and seeing what I can do about it.

Comment: Then maybe the System Protection is somehow corrupted and therefore is using more space than indicated. Try clear the restore points (do a disk backup before if possible), check that the folder is really empty (almost empty) and wait to see if it works fine now.

Comment: Alright, so I've deleted some of my Rescue and Recovery backups, but that didn't seem to do anything at all. I also deleted all my System Restore Points, but that only gave me back about 8 GB. So there's still 52 GB that I want to delete but have no idea how to.